# Using $query->field_data() in codeIgniter 2 / MySQL

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to use

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
$fields = $query->field_data();
```

which is documented at the bottom of this manual page
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/fields.html

but I get a list of errors (more than a 100 of these) with any query, even a simple `select * from tablename`.

I am using CodeIgniter 2, PHP Version 5.4.10, MySQL version 5.5.29

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `article`";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$fields = $query->field_data();
```

Error list (first couple of them):

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: stdClass::$Type Filename: mysqli/mysqli_result.php Line
>   Number: 89
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: stdClass::$Field Filename: mysqli/mysqli_result.php Line
>   Number: 95
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: stdClass::$Default Filename: mysqli/mysqli_result.php Line
>   Number: 97
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: stdClass::$Key Filename: mysqli/mysqli_result.php Line
>   Number: 99

Comment: The error appears in lines where framework tried to generate an object from field meta-data. 
    Try to execute select * from performance_schema.rwlock_instances where 
write_locked_by_thread_id is not null or read_locked_by_count is not null;  
    
    select * from performance_schema.mutex_instances where 
locked_by_thread_id is not null;

Maybe mysql locks meta-data i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed to be bug in codeIgniter, they fixed it in the developer branch
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/effd0133b3fa805e21ec934196e8e7d75608ba00